# Msgbox Show Two Times

Tags: vb.net

In Visual Basic 2012 When I Add Msgbox For Any Action Msgbox Show Two Times

My Msgbox Code

```
    Dim msg1
msg1 = MsgBox("Form2.show",MsgBoxStyle.Information Or MsgBoxStyle.YesNo,"Form2")

If msg1 = vbYes Then Form2.Show()

else

end if
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    Dim msg1
    msg1 = MsgBox("Form2.show", MsgBoxStyle.Information Or MsgBoxStyle.YesNo, "Form2")
    If msg1 = vbYes Then
        Me.Show()
    ElseIf msg1 = vbNo Then
        Me.Close() 'put here what you want to do
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: How on God's green earth did you figure out what the question was asking and post the correct answer? It looks to me like it's talking about showing a message box two times. Your code doesn't do this. May I borrow your crystal ball some time?

Comment: it showed the Form if he pressed yes and also if he pressed no.i tried the code in vs2012